# Angular 7: How to create unit test for lazy Loaded routers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, lazy-loading

I'm creating unit test cases for Dashboard component i.e a lazy loaded component.

In Dashboard component i'm using routerlink:

```
  <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link home" routerLink="/dashboard/home">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link profile" routerLink="/dashboard/profile">Profile</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link logout"  (click)="logout()">Logout</a>    
  </div>
```

The unit test case for this:

```
      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [DashboardComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent, RegistrationComponent, HomeComponent, ProfileComponent,
            HomePageListingComponent],
          imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
          ]
        })
          .compileComponents();
      }));

  it('should navigate to home page if clicked home navigation', fakeAsync(() => {
    const router = TestBed.get(Router);
    const location = TestBed.get(Location);

    router.initialNavigation();

    const loader = TestBed.get(NgModuleFactoryLoader);
    loader.stubbedModules = {lazyModule: PrivateModule};

    router.resetConfig([
      {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'lazyModule'},
    ]);

    const profileLink = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.profile')).nativeElement;
    expect(profileLink.text).toEqual('Profile');
    expect(profileLink.pathname).toEqual('/dashboard/profile');
    profileLink.click();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(location.path()).toBe('/dashboard/profile');

  }));
```

I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376125/angular-testing-with-lazy-loading-modules-routes) and tried to use the same concept but getting this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'lazyModule'

Is I'm missing something or any other approach to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: I haven't used the RouterTestingModule before but I would assume, you actually need to make the ProfileModule known or stub that module in your TestBed setup in order to be able to use this module inside the loader.stubbedModules. Do you think you could recreate this error in a stackblitz or anything similar. It would be easier to help.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig if i do use My lazy loaded module into TestBed start getting another error: 'Failed: Type DashboardComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: PrivateModule and DynamicTestModule! '

Comment: I'll try to add code on stackblitz.

Comment: Yes you would need to remove the components from your testbed declaration which are declared inside that module if you include the module. Otherwise you declare the same components twice. Ok create a stackblitz. I‘ll have a look.

Comment: have you tested to add `class PrivateModule { }` in the file and removed the import?

Comment: @Lucho the suggested changes landed me to another error : 'Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'PrivateModule'.'

Comment: add `DynamicTestModule `, import it and add to testbed imports array

Comment: @Lucho did you mean to add PrivateTestModule (DynamicTestModule) to imports array?

Comment: add it to your  `TestBed.configureTestingModule`